# Laravel write a query to find if access was enabled on date

Tags: mysql, laravel, date

I have a table called `system_access`. A user can have an access, but it has to be enabled. Accesses can be enabled and then disabled later and then enabled and disabled again for infinite number of times.

I have a table called `audits` which has the info of when there was an action of enabling or disabling the `system_access`.

What I need, is - in a given time, I need to find which system_accesses did user have that were enabled.

The audit table has the following structure: 
'id', 'action', 'system_access_id', 'created_at' .
'action' can be 'enabled' or 'disabled'

Comment: your description is not very clear to help you, try to post your database table structure and also your eloquent models if have..

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have your model relationships set correctly.

In your SystemAccess model include the following:

```
public function audits() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Audits'); // Put the actual path of your model here
}
```

Then you can query using Eloquent. One way (not the only way) would be to do something like this:

```
$access = SystemAccess::where('user_id', $userId)
->whereHas('audits', function($query) use($startDate,$endDate) {
    $query->where('status','enabled')
          ->where('created_at', '<=', $endDate)
          ->where('created_at', '>=', $startDate);
})->get();
```

The first `where` gets all system_access rows by the user id. The `whereHas` is used to query the relationship with the audits table, specifically we want to make sure we only get within your specified date range (hence the `$startDate` and `$endDate`), and also to only retrieve status if it is enabled.

Comment: the thing is that when a system_access gets enabled - I store 1 audit. When the system_access gets disabled, I store another audit with status 'disabled'